# Getting json resource throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, json

I've been trying to load my json file (LandInfo) from a res folder within my src folder.

[image]

I want to load the file in so that it can be parsed with Gson.

I've tried doing:

`getClass().getResource("res/LandInfo").toExternalForm()`

and

`new InputStream(getClass().getResourceStream("res/LandInfo"))`

since Gson#fromJSon accepts either a string or a reader

However, both options return null.

How would I go about finding the file in a correct manner?

Comment: Try with `/res/LandInfo` since you don't want path related to current location of class returned from `getClass` but from root location of your resources. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception

Comment: This still throws the same error

Comment: You should use `/LandInfo` as a resource path here; the `res` directory is marked as a directory on the classpath itself according to your image

Comment: I tried that out as well, but it gave me the same result

Comment: As your using intellij, I personally do it like this: 1. Right click on the file in explorer, and click copy file path. Paste the copied file path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getClass().getResource() loads resources from the directory in which your class is located (here "src/sample")
Thus the returned URL by this method would look like "src/sample/res/LandInfo" which is not correct.

Instead, you could use:

```
getClass().getResource("../res/LandInfo").toExternalForm()
```

and

```
new InputStream(getClass().getResourceStream("../res/LandInfo"))
```

Also make sure that your non-java files (resources) are copied into your build folder when using build managers such as Maven, Gradle, etc

Comment: Using this I've successfully been able to grab it. Thanks for the help